# Python lists -- deduping and adding sub-list element

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

Input:

`a = [[['a','b'],3],[['b','a'],9],[['b','z'],4]]`

Desired Output (dedupe regardless of order and add integers)

`[[['a','b'],12],[['b','z'],4]]`

This does not work of course:

```py
a2 = [sorted(list) for list in [i[0] for i in a]]

print(a2)

[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'z']]
```

which can be deduped of course:

```py
a3= [] 

for i in a2: 
    if i not in a3: 
       a3.append(i)

print(a3)

[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'z']]
```

But of course I am losing the counts for the sub-list being deduped.
Any advice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
a = [[['a','b'],3],[['b','a'],9],[['b','z'],4]]

# we use a dict to do the job.
# we sort the list of char and change to tuple. So i can be use as key.
dct = {}

for i in a:
    srt = tuple(sorted(i[0]))
    if srt in dct:
        # the tuple of char is already existing as key, just sum int.
        dct[srt]+= i[1]
    else:
        # if not we had a new key
        dct[srt] = i[1]
# Convert the dict to list of list
new_list = [[list(k),v] for k,v in dct.items()]
print(new_list) # [[['a', 'b'], 12], [['b', 'z'], 4]]
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you. Preferred answer because core python functionality (not package dependency, which do work as noted for those responses.)

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[['a','b'],3],[['b','a'],9],[['b','z'],4]]
d = defaultdict(lambda : 0)

for e, n in a:
    d[frozenset(e)] += n

a =  [[list(k), v]  for k, v in d.items()]
a
```

output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], 12], [['b', 'z'], 4]]
```

---

or you can use:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from collections import Counter

f = ({frozenset(k): v} for k, v in a) 
d = reduce(add, map(Counter, f)) # sum unique data
result = [[list(k), v]  for k, v in d.items()]
result
```

output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], 12], [['b', 'z'], 4]]
```

---

if you like one-line solution:

```
 [[list(k), v] for k, v in reduce(add, map(Counter, ({frozenset(k): v} for k, v in a))).items()]
```

output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], 12], [['b', 'z'], 4]]
```

Comment: Solutions work.  I preferred the accepted one for core python functionality, but these are nicely done.  The defaultdictionary package is a new one for me; so something to put into the tool box.    Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the sub-lists to frozensets first so that you can treat them as keys and use `collections.Counter` to add the integers as counts for each distinct key, and then convert the frozensets back to lists when iterating through the resulting items:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
for t, c in a:
    counter.update({frozenset(t): c})
print([[list(t), c] for t, c in counter.items()])
```

Comment: This is a clever answer but doesn't quite return the correct result: it doesn't sum the first two integers to return `12`, instead it returns `9`.  (I.e. `[[['b', 'a'], 9], [['z', 'b'], 4]]` not `[[['b', 'a'], 12], [['z', 'b'], 4]]`.

Comment: Oops. Fixed then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```py
from itertools import groupby

a = [[['a','b'],3],[['b','a'],9],[['b','z'],4]]

# this will ensure a is ordered by the merging key:
a=sorted(a, key=lambda x: sorted(x[0]))

# this will group by merging key, extract the value with index 1, and sum it:
a=[[k, sum(map(lambda z: z[1], v))] for k,v in groupby(a, key=lambda x: sorted(x[0]))]
```

Outputs:

```py
[[['a', 'b'], 12], [['b', 'z'], 4]]
```